# Elasticsearch Graph Based on Runtime Numeric Subfields

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have documents, with a structure along the lines of

```
{
   MyField: {
       subfield1: 3,
       subfield2: 100,
       ...
   }
}
```

The names of the subfields are dynamic, and there's no way to know which fields will be present when I'm creating the graph. Across all records, I want to a graph of which subfields have the highest value.

This would be easy if I knew the subfields ahead of time, however, they're arbitrary. In the ElasticSearch UI, it will only let me specific graph the subfields that are present at creation time. Is there any way to this for arbitrary future subfields?